# Warning: Ignoring platform 'android-19': build.prop is missing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

> Warning: Ignoring platform 'android-19': build.prop is missing

I went to SDK Manager, I installed all "Tools", **Android 1.6 (API4)** and all the "Extras"

My first SDK Manager, I installed "**Android 2.2 (API8)**" and "**Android 4.4.2 (API19)**" and I then deleted them.

When I open "Eclipse", I get in the "Console" this:

> [2014-03-09 11:24:14 - Android SDK] Warning when loading the SDK:
>   Warning: Ignoring platform 'android-19': build.prop is missing.

And when I go to **New > Android Application Project** like this:

> Application Name: Arrar Project Name: Arrar Package Name:
>   com.sasa.arrar Minimum Required SDK: API4:Android 1.6 (Donut) Target
>   SDK: API4:Android 1.6 (Donut) Compile With:Google APIs (Google Inc.)
>   (API4) Theme: None
>
> Next > Next > them "Create Activity", underneath it there is a red x and written "This template requires a minimum SDK version of at least 7, and the current min version is 4" and the Next not highlighted

Help? :)

Comment: Change minimum required SDK version to something more recent (10 for example - it is Android 2.3.4), because there are almost no devices left running older versions, not to mention that hardware on them is too old to run smoothly most of today applications.

Comment: A version like (10 for example Android 2.3.4) which used to be and deleted? I did that, it doesnt work, I tried Android 4.4.2 that existed then I removed it from SDK manager and the Android 2.2 as well

Comment: Just in case: [SDKM](http://oi61.tinypic.com/zkijw7.jpg)